# Can I set a default browsing app on windows 10?

Tags: apps, browser

After updating my windows phone from Windows 8.1 to 10  I see that the section for managing Apps for Website under System Settings. However I don't know or am sure if it is related with default browser. The section indicates:

> Some website can be opened by an app or a browser. Turn off an app to
>   open the website with a browser.
>
> Your browser is the only installed app that can open websites.

Also when I go to Phone I see **Default Apps** which has the description

> Choose the apps you want to use for things like caller ID, spam filtering and more.

So my questions can I be able to set a default browser app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot currently do this. The settings page you mentioned is so that apps can handle links related to their function (e.g. Readit might handle `reddit.com` or myTube might handle `youtube.com`). This does raise the question of whether or not an app could register itself to simply receive, for example, `http://*`, but unfortunately I don't have an answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that I have had much much about default option in W10M but literally all gone waste. Sorry but you can't do that at the moment. The section you're talking about is for the apps developed for a specific site and hence that site can be opened by that app. But it is nothing to do with default selection. Moreover what you have mentioned in latter part of your question is a characteristic of **Call settings ** and you can't set a default app for everything you want. Hopefully default selection in W10M may see the light of day.